# Excel question! How to use IF function with a 'less than' number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula in excel that will make a number appear in a cell, if ANOTHER cells number is under 200.

So for example

If column A1 has the number 3 in it, and Column B1 has the number 198 in it, then Column C should have a formula that automatically puts the number '3' from A1 in it, based on the fact that column B has a number under 200.

So, I basically want a formula in the C column that says 'If B is less than 200, display A in C column.

FYI I am using this formula, and it is returning a 0, but not displaying the number in the cell when over 200 : `=IF(N3=">200",L3,0)`

Comment: In `C1`, `=IF(B1<200,A1,"")`.

Comment: Or modifying the formula you provided, `=IF(N3>200, L3, 0)`. Including the quotation marks checks if `N3` is the *text* ">200", instead of a numerical comparison.

Comment: it's not working, because when I put in the " "  A1, it just says 'A1' in the C1 cell, and I need to do say the number which is in A1

Comment: Right, there *shouldn't* be quotation marks around `A1`.

Comment: Is "A1" & "B1" properly _number formatted_ ? If yes, C1=if(B1<200,A1,0) should work.

Answer (score 0):

In A1, I've put the value 3.
In B1, I've put the value 198.
In C1, I've put the formula `=IF(B1<200;A1)`, I see value 3.