# Excel IF function help required

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I have difficulties with IF in Excel. 
What I need is to auto populate a cell (d2) with "0,5" if the value of different cell (c2) is equal or less than "85". 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel question! How to use IF function with a 'less than' number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53055079/1578604)

Comment: @Jerry BTW less than or equal to... but a simple edit once you know...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=if(C2<=85,0.5,0)
```

Note: I tested with 0.5 not 0,5 because of my system. If your system is using different separators you may need something like :

```
=if(C2<=85;0,5;0)
```

Also note that I have put a 0 if C2 does not match - you may want a blank so "" instead of 0.

Comment: Please give the OP time to at least show their attempt first. Otherwise you're cheating them the opportunity to learn to create their own code and not motivating them to improve their question up to site standards.